# Refreshing current pages via js adds to BackButton history in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, webforms

I'm having a weird problem with an iframe refreshing it's parent: when I refresh the containing page, either directly through window.parent or through a message that is sent to the parent and the parent uses window.location.reload (or window.location=window.location or any of the various other ways of refreshing the current page), the Back Button history gets a new entry, so page1, page1, page1, page1 if I keep doing this.

This doesn't happen on my simplified test page, and it doesn't happen in FireFox at all. There's only one entry in chrome://history.

If I use the dev tools to add a link, with an onclick event that calls window.location.reload and then click on it, it doesn't get added to the back buttons history, if I use js to add a link and then call the click event, it does.

The only definite difference between my regular pages and my test pages, is that I don't have a bunch of telerik controls (radscriptmanager, radajaxmanager, radwindow managers) on my test pages.

Comment: I don't have a fix, but I am unclear about whether you want multiple histories or not, *and* what's happening in each browser. No history in Chrome at all? 1 entry in FF? It's just slightly unclear on all issues.

Comment: @wazz: Chrome has unwanted history…So, in Chrome I could easily have a “history” in the back button of a dozen “pages” that would actually be just one page, while FF would show just the one page.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying `replaceState` from the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method). You can force a URL change without it affecting the back button.

> history.replaceState() operates exactly like history.pushState() except that replaceState() modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one.

> replaceState() is particularly useful when you want to update the state object or URL of the current history entry in response to some user action.

The History API [has good browser support](https://caniuse.com/history) these days.

Comment: My problem isn't with the current URL/title, my problem is that history is being ADDED to when I'm just refreshing the page.

Comment: You can use the same API to fix it by checking the history stack and removing doubled entries. I'm not site why a reload is adding to state in the first place but it should be easy to correct for on load.

Comment: As best I can tell the history api doesn’t let you delete entries